# Check if Object has data or not?

Tags: java, object, null

I am calling method to get data as per passed text that will ping into database.

So I want to check if there is data arrived in object or not.

Code :

```
Method m = service.getMethodDataByFilter(text);
```

I have tried :

```
if(m == null){
    System.out.println("In NULL");
}
```

but it does not entering inside it.

I have also tried :

```
if(m.getName().isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("In NULL");
}
```

then it throws `NPE` in condition because no data received.

So how to check if there is data inside object or not ?

Method Class :

```
public class Method {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // getter-setter
}
```

**UPDATE**

Have just try [Ruchira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869846/ruchira-gayan-ranaweera)

```
    if(m== null){
        System.out.println("m is null");
    }else if(m.getName()==null){
        System.out.println("m.getName() is null");
    }else if(m.getName().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("m.getName() is empty");
    }
```

Still throws same `NPE`.

**FULL Method Code :**

```
public MethodDTO getMethod(String text){
    Method m = service.getMethod(text);

    if(m == null){
        System.out.println("m is null");
    }else if(m.getName()==null){
        System.out.println("m.getName() is null");
    }else if(m.getName().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("m.getName() is empty");
    }

    ModelMapper mapper = ModelMap.methodMapper();
    return mapper.map(m, MethodDTO.class);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of `getMethodDataByFilter`

Comment: because `m` is not `null` but  `m.getName()` is `null`

Comment: please show the code where it throws Null pointer exception

Comment: post your full code.. and full stack trace your are getting... exception is some where else.

Comment: I think your service is null. That's why it throws null pointer

Comment: read you stack trace or run in debug with automatic breakpoint on exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to :

```
if(myObject==null){   // check if object is null
System.out.println("myObject is NULL");
}
else{ // myObject should not be null here
if(myObject.getField1()==null) // check for fields within the object
{
System.out.println("field1 is NULL");
}
if(myObject.getField2()==null)
{
System.out.println("field2 is NULL");
}
...
}
```

Note if the object is null, then trying to access any *non-static* field / method on it will result in NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `if ( m == null || m.getName()== null)`. Note that apart from m its name may also be `null`.

Comment: No, `if ( m == null || m.getName()== null)` still shows `NPE` in `m.getName()`.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ no and never.. `if ( m == null || m.getName()== null)` will not give you `NPE`

Comment: I am making the reasonable assumption that `getName` is a simple getter.  If that is the case, the code will never give NPE because `||` will short circuit

Answer (score 0):

```
m == null
```

will return false when object `m` is not null but it does not check all its attributes recursively inside object.

```
m.getName()
```

seems to be returning null but even this statement will not throw NPE. But yes if you call `m.getName().isEmpty()` will throw NPE. You should better check like this:

```
if (m.getName() == null) //assuming you have already checked for m being null
```

Comment: No, `if (m.getName == null)` still throw `NPE`.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ m.getName will throw NPE when m is null or if you do something silly in getName method.

Comment: but I have not do any silly inside the `getName`, have just initialize the value.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ Update your code in your question with the latest copy.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation.

```
if(m == null){
  System.out.println("In NULL");
}
```

Since inside `if` not enter since `m` is not `null`. But

```
if(m.getName().isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("In NULL");
}
```

Here you get `NullPointerException` since `m.getName()` is `null`.

So you can try as follows

```
 if(m == null){
  System.out.println("m is null");
 }else if(m.getName()==null){
  System.out.println("m.getName() is null");
 }else if(m.getName().isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("m.getName() is empty");
 }
```

Comment: So how to check that `m` has received data or not ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ you can check my last part of the answer.

Comment: Have tried all 3 without else but it throws `NPE` at `m.getName()==null` and if remove it then throws same at `m.getName().isEmpty()`.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ you have to validate all the steps. coding is not a skipping

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera - I kind of disagree.. `m` and `m.getName()` are at different levels. Using `if(m==null){}else{ // check for fields of m.someMethod() here}` makes more sense.

Comment: @TheLostMind same logic execute here too.. you can check it.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera - What if the OP wants to check 2 fields?

Answer (score 0):

Check the object is null or not like this:

```
if(m != null && m.getName != null) {
 // Object m is not null and m.getName is also not null
} else {
 // Either Object m is null or m.getName is null or both are null
}
```